# RegEx to remove commented portion of code/lines/Tags in HTML or XHTML page

Tags: regex

I would require a RegEx in .NET in such a way that to remove the commented lines in HTML page/code where ever the tag  finds as commented portion or code.

For reference:

```
<!--loop output-------end-->
```

I want to remove the portion of commented code/line as above using RegEx.

Provide me a RegEx for the same.

Comment: It is **VERY** difficult to achieve using regex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 Use an html parser instead.

Answer (score 0):

For the code like javascript in HTML page, I suggest you to use [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)

For HTML, if you using .NET to generate HTML, you can just don't print out `<!-- -->` and `//` parts, isn't it?

Regexes are not very effective for that case.

Because, lets say, you put `//.*\n` to clear up comment lines, but in following XHTML, if you remove `//<![CDATA[` and `//]]>` , XHTML become broken.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
alert("<This is compatible with XHTML>");
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
str = str.ReplaceAll('<!--loop output-------end-->', '');
```